# I am using this Query function but it is not working well

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 3 sheets in this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vnrbi94vzxHcyvYtcr5IGKqJwXPtbu_cRAnDZOCXeXM/edit#gid=1327158077).

1. Data : Main Dataset
2. Data 2: 2nd Dataset
3. Data after removing Data 2: I want to filter out Main Dataset(Data sheet) that is not in 2nd Dataset.

I am using this but not working.

[image]

Any other method? that will solve my problem?

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example. I have modified as `=QUERY(Data!A1:K,"select * where not B matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,'Data 2'!B1:B)&"'")`. Does it work properly?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thank you. Can you please what is wrong with the above formula?

Comment: `'Data 2'!B1:B` is an array of values which is not supported by `QUERY`. My solution is to join the values into a string with `|` which is an 'OR logic' operator in regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(Data!A1:K, "where not B matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1,'Data 2'!B1:B)&"'")
```